# ¿Como puedo crear contenido personalizado de html5,css3,javascript en wordpress?

Tags: html5, css3, wordpress

Me encuentro trabajando en una empresa que maneja una plantilla de wordpress llamada "the 7" la cual incluye algo llamado "wp bakery page"que es un plugin con el que puedes crear contenido para una web de una manera muy facil, estilo wix... sin embargo para cuestiones de diseño y usabilidad no es la mejor herramienta, porque te limita graficamente, queremos cambiar toda la estructura del sitio, ahora me encuentro haciendo el home del sitio pero en html, ya la diseñadora me lo paso en photoshop, pero la verdad es que soy muy nueva en wordpress, he leido sobre child-themes pero no estoy muy segura de cómo implementar lo que codifique desde cero con HTML5, css3 y javacript y  crear paginas internas personalizadas de esta manera en wordpress, porque ademas no entiendo muy bien los llamados que hace wordpress para la estructura de los documentos y que asi mismo cuando lo pase a wordpress, pueda ser personalisable desde el panel de administrador.

¿Por donde empezar?

Comment: Esta pregunta es demasiado amplia. Lee [ask] y Edita la pregunta para intentar concretar más el problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te entiendo tuve estas mismas dudas hace poco tiempo y te doy un resumen que es lo que utilizo cada que realizo un tema para wordpress:

Dentro de wordpress hay una carpeta llamada "wp-content" en ella crea una carpeta con el nombre de tu tema.

Ahora en tu carpeta crea 2 archivos para tu nuevo tema: index.php y style.css.

Dentro de style.css indica el nombre de tu tema y datos entre /* */, algo como:

```
/*
    Theme Name: Nombre de tema
    Theme URI:
    Author: Tu Nombre
    Description: Descripción
    Version:1.0
    Licence: GNU General Public Licence o Later
    Tags: Tag
*/
```

Eso es lo básico para comenzar un tema. Después hay una estructura de WordPress mejor conocida como la jerarquía de temas que va saltando entre archivos dependiendo de como los crees y llames, aquí hay información:

https://decodecms.com/jerarquia-de-archivos-de-plantilla-en-wordpress/

También te dejo el loop:

https://neliosoftware.com/es/blog/como-funciona-el-loop-de-wordpress/

Entendiendo la jerarquía de temas todo será mas sencillo, pasando a un ejemplo de como lo trabajo después de crear el index.php así como el style.css paso a crear:

**header.php** donde incluyo los tags header de HTML5 y con PHP:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

**footer.php** donde incluyo los tags footer de HTML5 y con PHP:

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

**index.php** donde incluyo el header y el footer:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Sin embargo esto no quiere decir que index.php será la primer página que mostrara WordPress.

Cuando creas tu primer página de WordPress desde el administrador indicando que es tu página de inicio wordpress obtiene el slug "inicio" y busca un archivo llamado **front-page.php** así que debes de crear ese archivo y obtener el contenido que ingresaste desde el administrador, de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
get_header();
?>

<?php while (have_posts()): the_post();// traigo el contenido de la página desde la BaseDeDatos
 ?>

<?php the_title();?></h2> // el título que indicaste en el administrador

<?php the_content(); ?>// el contenido


<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Claro que puedes incluir etiquetas HTML5 para el formato.

La jerarquía de temas continua y si ya no estas en la página de inicio busca el siguiente archivo que es **page.php** que básicamente contiene lo mismo que **front-page.php** con la diferencia que este carga la información de cualquier otra página que no sea inicio o tenga el slug "inicio".

Page.php es muy importante ya que se aplica a todas las páginas menos a la principal o la de inicio.

Así puedes crear cada una de las páginas que necesites desde tu administrador y tomaran toda la estructura que indiques en **page.php** pero si una página va a tener otro formato diferente al indicado en **page.php** puedes crear un archivo con el nombre que necesitas por ejemplo si la sección de contacto será diferente debes crear: "contacto-page.php" y al inicio indicar su nombre:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Contacto Template

*/
?>
```

Hacer el loop como en page.php y agregar la estructura que necesites diferente a las demás páginas.

Esto es lo mas básico y lo que realizo, al inicio es intimidante pero poco a poco se vuelve rutinario y comienzas a hacer tus widgets y plugins.

Te recomiendo busques tutoriales en youtube o udemy, en lo particular te recomiendo:

https://www.udemy.com/experto-de-photoshop-a-wordpress-creando-2-themes-plantillas/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=95TKLrtNMx8&list=PLcNBm08RlSWln98zhVMIuMNu-J_hPCP1o

Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que crear un template de Wordpress. Un tema básico de Wordpress tiene los siguientes 4 archivos básicos:

```
header.php (Desde el doctype hasta el final del header de tu sitio)
index.php (Desde el final del header de tu sitio hasta el final del contenido de tu sitio)
footer.php (El footer del sitio)
style.css (Lo principal que tiene que contener es los detalles del tema)
```

Puedes utilizar el código que ya escribiste en un html para hacer esos archivos. Sólo tienes que cambiar algunas cosas para que funcione con Wordpress.

Ejemplo de header.php

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<header id="header-principal">
  <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>/assets/img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
</header>
```

Una de las diferencias es, en este caso, el atributo src de la etiqueta . Para que funcione en Wordpress necesitas utilizar alguna función para obtener la ruta absoluta al template, y después dar la ruta a la imagen dentro de la carpeta del template.

Tienes que aprender a utilizar las clases y funciones de wordpress para poder hacer dinámico tu template. (Cargar tus posts, imágenes, tus menús, etc). Te recomiendo leer y hacer pruebas con el codex de wordpress.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: Wow! si, bueno el header y el footer lo tengo controlado porque ya esta predeterminado, lo que debo modificar ahora es el index.php segun lo que he leido, entonces me pondre a leer la documentacion más a fondo, basicamente solo tengo archivos css y html que convertir.Es posible crearlo con un child theme? para no afectar el tema actual ya que por politicas de la empresa no lo puedo hacer.